# How to commit a file to the repo but make it so its future commits are not allowed?

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have a user-specific file in an Xcode project that I would like to push to the repo for the first time so it won't break the build (as the file is imported), but I want subsequent changes to it to stay with the users instead of being committed to the repo.  Is it possible to do this?

I would like to make the process automatic for all team members.  That is, the file is in the repo, but changes made by each developer won't be tracked.

Comment: What file is it? And why would lack of this file break the build?

Comment: You could write a server-side hook which ensures that pushes don't modify the file in question. Take a look at the [Git Hooks chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) of the progit book.

Comment: @MichałCiuba It's a file we include in the pch.  The content in the file is custom for each developer.